# Divide matrix using left division

Tags: matrices

In matlab, I defined

```
a=[1;2;3]
b=[4;5;6]
```

both a and b are not square matrix.

and execute `a\b` will return `2.2857`

From various sources, we understand that `a\b ~= inv(a)*b`, but in my case, `a` is not a square matrix, thus we can't perform an inverse operation on it.

I am actually translating matlab code to c#, and I need to know how do left division between non-square matrix calculated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab $a $\ $b =(a'a)^{-1}a'b$, i.e. $b$ is projected onto $a$.

A little bit more information: Consider,
$$
b \approx ax 
$$
where $x$ is unknown and there are no exact solutions i.e. $b$ and $a$ have many rows and few columns, then the typical way to solve this problem is to solve for $x$ by projecting $b$ onto $a$ or by taking the point on the space $a$, which is closest to be i.e. $b \approx P_ab=a(a'a)^{-1}a'b=ax$.

Comment: wow, how do you found this? Is it like any source we can view? Sorry, my matlab knowledge is only about 1 hour.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a source... I use this operation a lot for linear regressions so I have to know what it does.